# Trying to figure best machine learning technique to evaluate schedules for a telescope

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model, metric

I work for an astronomical observatory with two geographically separated telescopes. Users submit proposals in the form of *programs* consisting of multiple *observations*, and we are trying to automize our observation scheduling system. For many years, we have had "queue coordinators" (QCs) spend several hours per day coming up with multiple schedules of *observations* for the night depending on weather conditions.

Right now, the science staff is having a real issue formalizing what makes for a good schedule as a mathematical equation, and I don't think it can be boiled down to a simple equation given the number of variables. My thought was that if we assume that the schedules created by the QCs are "close enough" to optimal, we can train some assisted machine learning technique (which one, I am not sure) to, being fed the data, to produce a score indicating the fitness of a proposed schedule. (We do have many years of daily historical data of schedules that we could consider close enough to optimal to use for the training and testing.)

Here are examples of some of the variables, although I don't know all of policies yet:

1. We divide scientific programs into bands 1, 2, 3, and 4, with band 1 programs being of the highest importance: essentially, we must complete all band 1 programs, and if the conditions are not sufficient for a band 1 program, we work on a band 2 program, etc. The higher the number, the less programs we expect to complete in that band.
2. A program generally has enough data to be useful for scientific purposes when it hits 80% completion; before then, it is essentially uselesss. Completeness over 80% is much less valuable than hitting the 80% mark.
3. We have thesis vs. non-thesis programs within each of the bands, with thesis programs being worth slightly more than non-thesis programs.
4. Completing a long program should be worth considerably more than completing a short program.
5. Observations are best scheduled near zenith (when the target is right overhead), offset by a few degrees due to the way the mirrors are arranged on the telescope.
6. The target of an observation obviously has to be visible at the time it is scheduled, and have a certain distance from the moon to avoid lunar interference.

We keep running into problems with proposed scoring functions by science, who seem to think that this can be modeled as a function of two inputs, i.e. band and completion rate. For example:

1. One proposed function motivated the scheduler to start as many band 1 programs as possible, but had much less impetus to complete them to the point of scientific use.
2. One proposed function made completing programs overly valuable, so the scheduler was motivated to complete as many short programs as it could, which left long programs with not enough nights to be completed.

They have just been throwing functions at each other and multiplying functions by their slopes, etc, to try to find something that comes close to capturing the observatory policy, which is not working.

I'm a combinatorial design theorist and while I have taken courses in ML years ago, I can't think of the best assisted machine learning technique to train for this kind of problem.

Does anyone have any ideas? If this is posted to the wrong stack exchange, I apologize. Please direct me to the correct one. I considered mathematics but thought it was more appropriate here.

Thanks very much for any suggestions, as we are really unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: If you could get to some agreement on what the elements of an objective function that weights competing prospective schedules appropriately (which may be somewhat complicated and need to have weighting tuned over time), this sounds like a good fit for a linear program.  I think you will have some challenges with ML approach.  ML isn't going to be able to create the schedules, which is probably the bulk of the work, so I don't see too much value in pursuing that.  Is there a framework for the objective?

Comment: This is the direction that I want to go in, and we prototyped it. Given the size of the problems, we needed to use Gurobi since the open source solvers couldn't solve them. Unsurprisingly, ILPs also generated much better schedules than a genetic algorithm, which actually did reasonably well. The problem is coming up with a good objective function, which is essentially the same as coming up with a good fitness function for the genetic algorithm, which is what we're struggling with, and the scientists working on this don't seem to quite understand that the function wholly determines the results.

Comment: This is why I wonder, given the fact that we have about five years of daily data of schedules chosen by the schedule planners, if there is some ML technique we can feed the schedules to to determine what makes a good schedule, as there's an art to it that's difficult to capture algorithmically by a simple function. They're still working on this and I'm working on the algorithm prototyping for now, but I thought I'd check in with the experts to see if there was any ML techniques to capture what makes a "good" schedule based on historical data. Thanks, though, for confirming my strategy :-).